# The Bukkit method getItemMeta() is missing for the type ItemMeta

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

I'm trying to call getItemMeta() for a custom inventory method in Bukkit for a core plugin but cannot find this method.

```
ItemMeta upgradesMeta = upgradesMeta.getItemMeta();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer. I feel so stupid

```
    ItemMeta upgradesMeta = upgradesMeta.getItemMeta();
```

has to be switched to

```
    ItemMeta upgradesMeta = upgrades.getItemMeta();
```

because upgrades is the name of the ItemStack not the Meta.
In other words, you put the `ItemStack.getItemMeta();` rather than `ItemMeta.getItemMeta();`